# Código VBA Excel

Tags: excel-vba

Fala Galera!

Preciso criar um código que copie uma lista horizontal de uma planilha e cole em outra planilha na forma vertical. Cada vez que o comando é executado, ele deve pular a linha para copiar a próxima informação. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tem um exemplo prático de como ficaria essa copia com uma informação de exemplo ? Qual o código que tem desenvolvido até ao momento ?

Answer (score 1):

Tem aqui um exemplo, basta escolher a Sheet onde quer fazer a alteração, coluna e linha de origem e destino e numero de elementos:

Sub HorizontalToVertical()

```
Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Const numeroElementos = 10

Const linhaInicialOrigem = 1
Const columaInicialOrigem = 1

Const linhaInicialDestino = 2
Const colunaInicialDestino = 2

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer


    For Y = 0 To numeroElementos
        dest.Cells(colunaInicialDestino, Y + linhaInicialDestino).Value = Source.Cells((X * stepSize) + (Y + linhaInicialOrigem), columaInicialOrigem)
    Next Y

End Sub
```